# Conditional attempts with nodejs Kue

Tags: node.js, redis, kue

I'm using [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) in one web crawler application. I want to set `attempts` for certain failed jobs if the errors match specific conditions. For instance if the error is caused by socket hang up, the job will retry for 3 times with 1 min interval.

My code is something like below but does not work

```
var kue = require('kue');
var queue = kue.createQueue();
queue.process('grab', function (job, done){
    //doCrawlingJob is async call and returns promise
    doCrawlingJob(job).then(function(result){
       done();
    }.catch(function(err){
        if (err.message.indexOf("socket hang up") >= 0) {
            job.attempts(3).backoff({delay:60*1000});
            job.save(function(){
               done(err);
            });
        } else {
            done(err);
        }
    );
});
//...
var job = queue.create('grab', data).removeOnComplete(true).save();
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score -1):

This may not answer your question but I noticed that you have some formatting errors in the code snippet. Try adding some brackets like so:

```
queue.process('grab', function (job, done){
    //doCrawlingJob is async call and returns promise
    doCrawlingJob(job).then(function(result){
       done();
    }).catch(function(err){
        if (err.message.indexOf("socket hang up") >= 0) {
            job.attempts(3).backoff({delay:60*1000});
            job.save(function(){
               done(err);
            });
        } else {
            done(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why was this downvoted? his code will never work because it doesn't have brackets around the 'then'